# How to call methods before initializing renderer [Wpf]

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My question about title. I created a steam application and I use `Steamworks.NET` for steam initialization. Site says:

> Open the Visual Studio solution (.sln) file, build both targets one
>   for Windows and one for OSX & Linux. (Optional if you downloaded a
>   prebuilt version) Reference the built assembly (Steamworks.NET.dll) in
>   your project. Start coding! Call SteamAPI.Init() before initializing
>   your renderer.

And I tried to call it with load event but it crashed every time.

Here my calling code:

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  SteamAPI.Init();
  SteamAPI.RestartAppIfNecessary(new AppId_t(911310));
}
```

And I tried:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        SteamAPI.Init();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

How can I call that method before rendering?

---

## Solved

Solved with using different SDK.

Comment: Did you try the `Main` method?

Comment: `Main` method ? I think i did.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Application.Startup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

You can attach it in the "App.xaml" file like this:

```
<Application
    x:Class="SomeApp.App.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeApp.App"
    Startup="App_OnStartup">
    <Application.Resources>       
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then add the handler in "App.xaml.cs":

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        SteamAPI.Init();
    }
}
```